# Html with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I used a php variable to set an ID in a html.php website. Now I want to use Modals with those Buttons

```
< tr class="button" id="< ?php echo $unique ?>">
```

This is what my JS looked like when my id was called "homeBtn" 
How do I get the $unique into my Java Script? its on the var btn as well as in the foreach.

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.querySelectorAll('homeBtn');

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


[].forEach.call(homeBtn, function(el) {
  el.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
  }
})

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's look at your code:

The following gets a reference to an element `<div id="myModal>`

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
```

This returns an array of all `homeBtn` elements `<homeBtn id="whatever">`

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('homeBtn');
```

And the following gets all elements with a class of `close` and then returns the first one found `<div class="close">`

```
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
```

The following code will fail because you have not defined a variable homeBtn anywhere in your code, possibly you meant btn?

```
[].forEach.call(homeBtn, function(el) {
  el.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
  }
})
```

Also, it is unnecessary and also impractical to attach event handlers in this manner.  When you want to attach an event handler to multiple elements, do so by attaching the event handler to their closest static parent then you can use `e.target` to access the element that was clicked. But I don't know why you would have multiple homeBtns in the first place...

Instead, I would do this:

```
document.getElementById("closestStaticParent")
  .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.id = "home") modal.style.display = "block";
  });
```

This code is more or less OK:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get Posts out of a Database. When you click them you get see whatever content the Post has. So I want to make a loop, where the Buttons get names, in my case its $unique which gets the ID of the Post attached, and when you click on a Post it opens the Modal with the id= to the posts id. But to make them different I wanted to gave them Names, and when you click it JS takes that name and opens it